# Laser scans of buildings / cities

Tags: data, lidar

I am looking for a point cloud source of laser scanned building. I have found Laser scans of Earth surface, but there is no open archive of scanned cities / buildings. Or is there something?

Comment: This would seem suitable to research/ask at the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 2):

As you didn't specify the location: The Netherlands has AHN2 (complete) and AHN3 (not complete yet).

AHN2 browser http://ahn2.pointclouds.nl/

AHN3 downloads https://www.pdok.nl/nl/ahn3-downloads
Hit a tile an click Puntenwolk LAZ Download

Not sure what the exact specs are but AHN3 should have better resolution. Buildings are recognizable in AHN2.

Comment: I dont care about location, I just need some real-life data for testing